# Best method for testing android kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, android, drivers, testing

I would like to test some of the features of android kernel like inserting a module and collecting certain parameters for research purpose. What would you think the best method for that?

Comment: I'd insert a module and collect certain parameters. I don't understand what you're asking: are you having trouble inserting a module? Trouble finding values of the parameters you're interested in? Trouble retrieving the data from the device? Something else?

Comment: @Gilles I havent done inserting module. Was asking which is the best way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go ahead with [android emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) where you can compile android kernel and mess around without hurting anyone. Also check out [this white paper](http://www.coverity.com/library/pdf/a-look-inside-the-android-kernel.pdf) on android kernel and it testing.